# Compare numbers excluding suffix in sql

Tags: sql, optimization, profiling

ID numbers in my database have a code embedded in the last 3 characters.  When comparing these ids for equality sometimes it is allowable to ignore the last 3 characters.

I.e. `12345001 == 12345009` should be true.

I usually do this with the following where clause:

```
where floor(id1/1000) == floor(id2/1000)
```

but in the case where I know id1 is stored in 'base' form where the last 3 digits are zero the following would also work:

```
where id1 == floor(id2/1000)*1000
```

It would also be possible with use of substring.

---

**Q:** Can anybody tell me from experience which of these three methods is the most efficient, or recommend the best (most accurate) way to profile these three different queries.

Thanks.

Comment: #winces# you're not usually supposed to include meaning in `join` columns (natural keys, yes).  What you're describing sounds like you have another table trying to break out (basically a `category` table) that contains the first n digits as the key, and sub-tables with the final 3 digits.  Oh, and if you're doing integer math, you shouldn't need the `FLOOR()` function - the results should be truncated (on DB2 at least, and that's _probably_ part of the standard...)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @XZero.  Regarding including meaning in the join column, I know that it should be two columns, but its a big, old app and I don't think any one will take the time to fix this in all the situations it occurs... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running either id value through a function will prevent any index use & the simple mathematic operations on integers would be faster than a cast to a character type followed by a substring comparison.

If you wanted to optimise this fully you could add a computed column to derive `floor(id/1000)`, then index that and use it in your `WHERE` clause.

(Another one for you to benchmark `abs(id1-id2)<1000` but basic series of mathematical transforms like this would only have temporal significance over huge datasets)

Comment: That `ABS(id1 - id2) < 1000` won't return the desired results (`12346001` will equate to `12345699`, not what the OP wants).